# THREE.js does not provide an export named EventDispatcher while loading OrbitControls in main.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

### Description

I am trying to use the `OrbitControls` from THREE.js in my project. When I attempt to import the `OrbitControls` object, I am getting the following error message in the Google Chrome DevTools console.

> The requested module './three.js' does not provide an export named 'EventDispatcher'

When I manually inspect `three.js` (r119), I can see that it does export `EventDispatcher` on line 50631.

**Question**: Given this information, why am I getting the aforementioned error message, and how can I fix this?

### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <script src="three.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### main.js

```js
import { OrbitControls } from './OrbitControls.js'
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to Steve, the root cause of my issue was that I was using the non-module version of `three.js` instead of the correct one (for my use case) called `three.module.js`. If you're getting the error message, make sure you're downloading the `three.module.js` file.

Comment: OrbitControls are not included in `'three'` instead you need to import them from examples, something like this: `'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls`

Comment: @George Yeah, I should have mentioned that I already downloaded `OrbitControls.js` and included it in my project. It's that script that's throwing the error message. It's weird, because `three.js` clearly exports `EventDispatcher`, but `OrbitControls.js` doesn't seem to pick up on it

Comment: Also, just FYI I'm not using a bundler. I literally just have an HTML page and a few JavaScript files locally.

Comment: Then just import as i stated above instead of downloading it directly. it's probably trying to import something from three relatively but can't because it's no longer in the examples folder. See Orbit controls first lines `import {
 EventDispatcher,
 MOUSE,
 Quaternion,
 Spherical,
 TOUCH,
 Vector2,
 Vector3
} from "../../../build/three.module.js";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the OrbitControls.js found in https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js

You're mixing the module library with the non-module library. If you look at the first lines of `OrbitControls.js`

```
import {
    EventDispatcher,
    MOUSE,
    Quaternion,
    Spherical,
    TOUCH,
    Vector2,
    Vector3
} from "../../../build/three.module.js";
```

It's trying to import variables from `../../../build/three.module.js`, which probably doesn't exist. From your error message, it seems like someone already edited it to be './three.js', which sounds like the non-module version.

### Solutions

#### Preserving references

- Download all of `three.js` to a folder (like `lib/three`)
- (Optionally) Delete files you don't need

Import via:

```
import { OrbitControls } from './lib/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import * as THREE from './lib/three/build/three.module.js';
```

#### Modifying only the files you need

Or you can download only the files you need and change the references:

- Download `three.module.js` from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/build/three.module.js
- Replace `../../../build/three.module.js` in `OrbitControls.js` to the appropriate path. It should be where `three.module.js` is in relationship to `OrbitControls.js`
- Delete the `<script src="three.js">` tag in your HTML, since `OrbitControls.js` directly imports it

#### Linking to a CDN

Alternatively, you can link directly to a CDN, like:

```
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.119.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.119.1/build/three.module.js';
```

This works because all of the required files are hosted by the CDN

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and now I'm getting a similar error `The requested module './three.js' does not provide an export named 'MOUSE'`.

Comment: I'd search all your files for where you're importing from `./three.js` and replace it with `./three.module.js`. Or I guess you could just rename `three.module.js` to `three.js`

Comment: The edit you made with the CDN imports worked! I think you're also correct about me mixing the module vs. non-module version of `three.js`. That's probably why your CDN example worked, because you're pointing to the module version of it. Cheers!