# Three JS - window.onload first displays scene too small before resizing when opening browser

Tags: three.js

I am learning WebGL and I want to do something basic: whenever I open `index.html`, I want the rendered scene to fit the window. However, when I try running my code (that I adapted from the WebGL tutorials), for a split second, the scene is displayed at a small size before being resized. Visually, this is jarring. How do I prevent that from happening?

My two files:

1. `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1">-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ThreeJS Rotation</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. `js/script.js`:

```
// import * as THREE from './three.module.js'
//
// import {OrbitControls} from "./OrbitControls";

// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269365/three-js-does-not-provide-an-export-named-eventdispatcher-while-loading-orbitcon
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.119.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.119.1/build/three.module.js';

// import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();


// Add background image
// scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x19d7f8);
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
scene.background = loader.load('https://assets.imgix.net/hp/snowshoe.jpg')

// Arguments:
//      1) Field of Value (degrees)
//      2) Aspect ratio
//      3) Near clipping plane
//      4) Far clipping plane
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50 , window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000 );
camera.position.set(0, 0, 5 )

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

// // Need to set size of renderer. For performance, may want to reduce size.
// // Can also reduce resolution by passing false as third arg to .setSize
// renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
// Add the rendered to the HTML


document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

function resizer() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    let height = window.innerHeight;

    let backgroundImg = scene.background;
    let bgWidth = backgroundImg.image.width;
    let bgHeight = backgroundImg.image.height;
    let texAspect = bgWidth / bgHeight;
    let aspect = width / height;
    let relAspect = aspect / texAspect;
    scene.background.repeat = new THREE.Vector2( Math.max(relAspect, 1), Math.max(1/relAspect,1) );
    scene.background.offset = new THREE.Vector2( -Math.max(relAspect-1, 0)/2, -Math.max(1/relAspect-1, 0)/2 );

    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
}

window.onload = resizer
window.addEventListener('resize', resizer)

var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
// Prevent Ctrl + Mouse from panning
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.update();


// A BoxGeometry is an object that contains all points (vertices) and fill (faces)
// of the cube
// const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();

// // Allegedly, BoxBufferGeometry is faster
// const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry();
// // Determines surface color (maybe texture?)
// const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
//
// // Mesh takes a geometry and applies the material to it
// const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
//
// scene.add( cube );


// Add arrow variables
const arrowDirection = new THREE.Vector3();

// Center of screen
const arrowPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

//
// const arrowPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);

//
// const arrowPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
arrowDirection.subVectors( scene.position, new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)).normalize();


const arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( arrowDirection, arrowPosition, 1, 0xffff00, 0.6, 0.4);
scene.add( arrow );


// This somehow creates a loop that causes the rendered to draw the scene
// every time the screen is refreshed (typically 60fps)
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    // arrow.rotation.x += 0.01;
    // arrow.rotation.y += 0.01;
    // cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    // cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    controls.update();
}
animate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set the renderer size before adding the renderer canvas to the dom

```
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;

renderer.setSize(width, height);

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```